# Don't recycle old instance of same activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, instance

I have a UserProfile Activity which is composed of different RecyclerView in tabs, there is a tab friends where i can click another user and a new instance of the same UserProfile will start.
The only problem is when i go press back from an instance: i've overrided the OnBackPressed which only contains finish() method, i will be redirected to the previous UserProfile instance, but all the RecyclerView and the profilePicture in the activity are still the same of the activity i've just finished.

I think it's due to the fact that they are RecyclerView but don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Are you using static fields in your activity?

Comment: yep, just find that the problem were static fields